# Issue with running Spark SQL query - column not found

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am working on Spark SQL, and I have created a data frame known as cars4 with the following code:

```
scala> val cars4 = spark.sql("SELECT maker, model, round(avg(mileage),0) avg_mileage, round(avg(price_eur),0) avg_price FROM cars_make_model_avgmileage_avgprice GROUP BY maker, model ORDER BY maker ASC, model ASC")
```

Which looks like this:

```
cars4.show(30)
```

[image]

Then I create a view:

```
cars4.createOrReplaceTempView("cars_make_model_mileage_price_ratio")
```

Then, when I try to get the division of the avg_mileage and avg_price from the above dataframe using the following code:

```
val cars5 = spark.sql("SELECT maker, model, round(avg_mileage/avg_price,0) mileage_price_ratio FROM cars_make_model_mileage_price_ratio GROUP BY maker, model ORDER BY mileage_price_ratio ASC")
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I have checked and the data frame cars4 has the following columns:

[image]

Then why does it say that avg_mileage cannot be found in the screenshot with the error? Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need a `group by` for `round` function. It is not an aggregate function, nor you're performing any in your final query.

Comment: Not sure why it got down voted. The answer is straightforward, but that should not matter, the question is asked in a clear way so I voted it back up

Answer (score 2):

In this query:

```
SELECT maker, 
    model, 
    round(avg_mileage/avg_price,0) 
    mileage_price_ratio 
FROM cars_make_model_mileage_price_ratio 
GROUP BY maker, model 
ORDER BY mileage_price_ratio ASC
```

You are doing a group by on maker and model (col 1 and col 2), but you are not performing any aggregate on col3 and col4, which is leading to this error:

- col3 and col4 are neither present in group by nor in aggregate.

For aggregation options, check this out - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg

Comment: Seems that I will have to learn more about aggregation. Thanks for sharing the page. I am newbie so a lot of things are not making much sense to me on that page.